# Trouble with enabling gzip configuration with http2 on tomcat 8.5.63 configured as reverse proxy above nginx server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat8

We are using tomcat as reverse proxy server which internally forwards our html/css/js request to application which is deployed on nginx server. We have enable the http2 and gzip configuraton on tomcat reverseproxy as shown below.

```
 <Connector
                SSLEnabled="true"
                acceptCount="25"
                address="10.xx.x.x"
                ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
                clientAuth="want"
                compressibleMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,application/json,application/javascript,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml,application/swagger-v20+json,application/swagger-v20+yaml"
                compression="on"
                compressionMinSize="1024"
                connectionTimeout="30000"
                disableUploadTimeout="true"
                keyAlias="tomcat"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
                maxThreads="200"
                minSpareThreads="5"
                noCompressionStrongETag="false"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                port="443"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                server="MyTomcat"
                socket.soReuseAddress="true"
                sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                >
<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" compressibleMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json" compression="on" compressionMinSize="1024" useSendfile="false" />
</Connector>
```

What we observed that with http1.1 gzip configuration is working fine with assets residing in nginx server.
but when we enable the http2 we can see the protocol switch to http2 but gzip configuration is not enable and also server header is not override. for the asserts residing in nginx server header is having a value of server: nginx/1.20.1.

Any thoughts about how we can enable the gzip configuration with http2 ?

Comment: There is a typo in your configuration: it is [`compressibleMimeType`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation), not `compressableMimeType`. Besides that the lists for HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 differ.

Comment: Hi thanks for you input but this does not solve the problem. One observation i could see the assets located on tomcate itself gzip is enable but we could not observe gzip for the assets located on nginx server.

Comment: Tomcat is not (usually) a reverse proxy, so you probably meant: you are using NGINX as a reverse proxy for Tomcat, which forwards requests for non-static resources to Tomcat. If this is the case you should look into NGINX configuration (Tomcat never sees the requests for static resources), otherwise please mention which library are you using to turn Tomcat into a reverse proxy.

Comment: Its our home grown library which turn tomcat into reverse proxy. We are maintaining the mapping internally through conf file and our code forward a request to nginx server and get the response and forward the response to the caller. Mapping is something like this /context/ui   /localhost:7441/ui

Comment: You also lack the `noCompressionStrongETag="false"` attribute on the `<UpgradeProtocol>`.

Comment: Hi Piotr Thanks it works for me adding noCompressionStrongETag="false"